# $(window).height() android 4.1 javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm coding mobile site and noticed strange behavior, my phone is android 4.1 and $(window).height() shows me 563px, my resolution on this phone is 1280, so 1280 minus addressbar and notification bar can't be 563 :-)

I tried screen.height function which returns correct 1280px value.

I'm tried to scale an image, and noticed if I scale image to 1200 (also tried 800) it is too big for screen.

On my tablet which is android 4.0 everything works correctly, so I can finish my site, because it is working good an tablet (used screen height) and for phone (screen height * ~0.5)

Of couse it is important to properly set height without $(window).height() for hide address bar.

Any idea?

Comment: Are the reported numbers possibly [density-independent pixels](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms)?

Comment: [What does this jsbin show you?](http://jsbin.com/limi/1/edit) (It's based on `.innerHeight` and `.innerWidth`.)  What does it show you when you turn the phone sideways?

Comment: @Pointy it shows me 1462  (portrait) or 362 (landscape)

Comment: @YaPKnn wow.  What kind of phone is it?  My HTC One has a "real pixel" resolution of 1280x640, but the browser shows 640x320 (minus the browser status bar).

Comment: @Chris This is values which I write down from alert() javascript function. I think the bigger value is physical resolution and lower is effective resolution.

Comment: @Pointy this is Alcatel One touch Idol Ultra and it has real resolution 720 x 1280.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for comments, now I know that I have a lot of work, and can't use screen.height for hidding address bar because it reports real resolution instead of effective....